# Mantener sesión abierta cuando cierro y vuelvo a abrir la página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estoy intentando hacer un **login** en el **frontend** y tengo un problema que no logro solucionar:

En una misma página tengo un formulario de login y un panel de usuario. Cuando pulso **Entrar** el formulario se oculta y se muestra el panel y cuando pulso en **Cerrar sesión** ocurre lo inverso.

Además tengo un **localStorage** donde almaceno el nombre que se escribe en el formulario.

El problema es que cuando cierro la página con la sesión abierta y la vuelvo a abrir me envía otra vez al formulario, manteniendo el valor pasado por el **localStorage**, yo quiero que al recargar la página o cerrarla y volverla a abrir (con la **sesión abierta**) me aparezca el panel de usuario y no el formulario, así una vez que pulse en "Cerrar sesión" se elimine el valor del **localStorage**.

Les dejo el código:

```js
let containerFrm = $('#container-form')
containerPanel = $('#container-panel'),
  formulario = $('#frm');

containerPanel.hide();

formulario.submit(function(e) {
  let nombre = $('#nombre').val();

  containerFrm.hide();
  containerPanel.show();

  localStorage.setItem('nombre', nombre);

  let nombreGuardado = localStorage.getItem('nombre');

  if (nombreGuardado != null && nombreGuardado != 'undefined' && nombreGuardado != '') {

    containerPanel.html('<h1>Bienvenido, ' + nombre + '</h1>').append('<a href="" id="logout">Cerrar sesión</a>');

    $('#logout').click(function() {
      containerPanel.hide();
      containerFrm.show();
      localStorage.clear();
    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-form">
  <form id="frm">
    <input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Entrar">
  </form>
</div>

<div id="container-panel">
  <div id="sesion"></div>
</div>
```

Yo supongo que me falta aplicar alguna función o método. Ya busqué por todos lados. ¡Si alguien me tira una ayuda agradezco!

**Nota:** al ejecutar el código acá me da un error del **localStorage**.

Comment: Ya trataste de ver si el navegador que usas permite guardar y/o en su defecto usar javascript junto con localStorage? Acuérdate que tiene cierta compatibilidad con navegadores.

Comment: Sisi, el localStorage funciona en mi navegador (es Chrome). Pero nose si es eso el factor del problema

Comment: Cada vez que cierres la ventana puedes guardar cual es la url antes de cerrar asi al iniciar puedes revisar si existe un valor en localstorage recargas la pagina y lo borras de localstorage, lo guardaras nuevamente cuando se cierre la ventana

Comment: necesitas que te ayuden las cookies